# Cutting string into parts

Tags: java, android, string

I want to cut a string receiving from a server into parts and have those individual parts shown in the corresponding `textView` element.

The first character is the label(1,2,3,4,...) of the string and correct textView element the last one is an identifier that the next character is again the label of another part.

The individual string parts have a length of 8, including the start and end characters.

I'm a complete beginner so any help is appreciated especially if you have some good tutorials.

Comment: yourText.subString(firstCharacter,endCharachter);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: It answers how to split, but not how to send the string to the appropriate textview based on the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to split a string and know where the split indexes are, `substring` is your friend

```
String s = // String received from server
int beginIndex = // first index
int endIndex = // end index (exclusive)
String substringOfS = s.substring( beginIndex, endIndex );
```

If the strings are separated by a particular delimeter (eg. space), then you can use the `split` function

```
String s = // String received from server
String[] parts = s.split( " " );
```